# How I give LineChart DataEntry using x label index and y value in ios-charts Charts '3.0.4'?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How I give LineChart Entry using x index and y value in [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) '3.0.4'???

am using `ChartDataEntry()` it is only available x value and y value. how i give x label index.

```
let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: xvalues[i], y: yAxisValues[i])
```

In My case I Have List Of Months With Year It is X-axis labels or values And Y Values That is Double.

Comment: Are you using this one - [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

Comment: @LalKrishna Yeah this Charts.